# Why does SQL Server Mgmt Studio 17.9 save MDF to C:\Users? Error: Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 CREATE FILE access denied

Tags: sql-server, ssms, localdb

I get the error

> Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file

after launching a localDb server and trying to run a `create database` query off it. I am very new to SQL Server and need to do a tutorial for an internship I am starting.

I created a localdb instance in my onedrive directory. At least I think I did because that's the directory I navigated to when I ran the

```
sqllocaldb c "LocalDBdemo" 14.0.1000.169
```

command on my command prompt (I use Hyper):

[image]

So why is it that SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1 is trying to create an `.MDF` file in my `C:\users\` directory?

[image]

It wants to put it in `C:\users`. Why not put it into the directory I created in Onedrive?

A solution I saw which I did was to make my `c:\users` directory accessible to everyone under permissions. I didn't want to do it but I did and it worked. But why do I even need to do this when I am running the program from within my windows user admin account which is the only account on my computer? Also how do I get SQL Server Mgmt Studio to create my `.MDF` databases wherever I choose?

Comment: Side note: "[The] windows user admin account ... is the only account on my computer" -- Do non-administrational work with a non-administrator user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify an appropriate location when you create a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE Customer 
ON (NAME='Customer_Data', FILENAME='C:\AppropriatePath\Customer.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME='Customer_Log', FILENAME='C:\AppropriatePath\Customer.ldf');
```

Comment: wow thanks. So this brings up a major issue. I don't know anything about SQlL. I was told to learn it though. The tutorials I see on youtube don't mention any of this stuff. They just make a database and start rolling. To that respect, I need to ask, what does LOG ON do? Why do you have a Log thing there instead of just leaving it at just: CREATE DATABASE Customer 
ON (NAME='Customer_Data', FILENAME='C:\AppropriatePath\Customer.mdf')  @Greg Low

Comment: Where can I go to get a good succinct tutorial that covers basics and build up properly to more intricate commands @Greg Low

Comment: Try the doco for CREATE DATABASE. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-7914]

Comment: I'll assume that even though I am on SQl server 2017/SMSS 17.9, these commands will work as well even though it says SQl 2019

Comment: Yes, just the same. Where they are specific to a version or edition, it typically calls that out. You can't do everything with localdb but you can do most things.

Comment: Yeah I just need somehting to practice with and they said localdb can do just that @Greg Low